# Adding to LinkedList changes initial value

Tags: java, list, linked-list, iterator, integer

This segment of code is supposed to iterate over a LinkedList containing Lists containing a sequence of numbers up to 9. The point is to change one number to its negative counterpart, then adding the list changed by one number back to the LinkedList containing all permutations. For example: for the set 1 2 3, the permutations go to 8, beginning with `[1 2 3]`, after the first iteration, it should contain a list of `[[1 2 3] ,[-1 2 3]]`, the second iteration should contain a linked list of `[[1 2 3], [- 1 2 3], [1 -2 3], [-1 -2 -3]]`, and so on. 
The end length of the Linked list should be `2^n`, which is correct for the final output, however, the actual data is completely wrong.

Problem: The output shows only the first number of the list as a negative number, so for the example above, only `(-1 2 3)` printed 8 times. This confuses me, as the first `List<Integer>` in the Linked List is (1 2 3). How does this program change the initial object in my list, and why does it keep adding a list with only the first integer changed? Thanks,

```
//Will make neg for one place in each list in linked list, adding changed 
//list back to linkedlist
public void makeNeg(Integer place){
    Integer target = 0;
    List<Integer> hold = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //list is a class variable
    Iterator<List<Integer>> it = list.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        hold = it.next();
        target = hold.get(place);
        target *= -1;
        hold.set(place, target);
        list.addLast(hold);
    }
}

//Should run program
public void run(Integer place){
    if(!(number > place)){
        System.out.print("---Completed Successfully ---\n");
    }else{
        makeNeg(place);
        run(place+1);
    }
}

Output for Integer of 3
-1 +2 +3 
-1 +2 +3 
-1 +2 +3 
-1 +2 +3 
-1 +2 +3 
-1 +2 +3 
-1 +2 +3 
-1 +2 +3
```

Comment: You have only one list `hold` and mutate this single list inline, adding references to it repeatedly to your `token` list. You need to make copies of your `hold` list.

Comment: What is `list`, and why do you initialize `hold` to an new `ArrayList` when you immediately replace that list with the `hold = it.next()` statement? Also, are you under the mistaken impression that `token.addLast(hold)` will add a *copy* of `hold`?

Comment: ... I might be under the mistaken impression that token.addLast(hold) will add a copy of hold. It only adds the address doesn't it, and not adding a copy

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to answer this question by using some code from this link (http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/). I made a object that implements serializable, and used this bit of code found at the url I linked.

```
public static numbers copy(numbers orig) {
    numbers obj = null;
    try {
        // Write the object out to a byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(orig);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        // Make an input stream from the byte array and read
        // a copy of the object back in.
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));
        obj = (numbers)in.readObject();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```